# Dartium/content shell unable to run tests

Tags: testing, dart, dartium

When running tests with

> pub run test -p dartium (or content-shell)

Although the broser is open with a blank page, every test fails with the same output:[image]

The browser.dart file is an *ad hoc* made one:

```
@TestOn("browser")
import "package:test/test.dart";
import "dart:html";
void main(){
  test("it works!", (){
     expect(true, isTrue);
  });
}
```

I even tried by adding a browser.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Browser test</title>
     <link rel="x-dart-test" href="browser.dart">
     <script src="packages/test/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>It works</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Still failing with the same error >.<

Comment: What Dart, Dartium and test package version are you using?

Comment: Dart VM version: 1.19.1
Chromium 45.0.2454.104 (Build para desarrolladores) (64 bits)
test-0.12.15+6

Comment: Hard to tell. You could try to delete the `.pub` directory and run `pub get` or `pub upgrade` again on your project or perhaps even `pub cache repair`. If it's such a simple test, it should just work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content shell is executed with *--dump-render-tree [custom_ad_hoc_url]* options by the test package that ends up in a bug, at least in my system (sth related to fonts, I think)

The workaround that I did was to just make an executable that omits that first option, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#/usr/bin/content_shell
/path/to/content-shell-dir $2
```

Comment: My suggestion is to just not use `content_shell`. The only advantage is that `content_shell --dump-render-tree` doesn't open a window but if you remove that option there is no point left for using `content_shell`. I hope the option to start chromium without a window will land eventually (seems they are working on that but I don't know about progress).

Comment: dartium takes more than 50 seconds to load in my system, I had to hack content-shell to don't convert into a skeleton waiting while I develop.
I suggested in Github an improvement to that last thing: [https://github.com/dart-lang/test/issues/465](https://github.com/dart-lang/test/issues/465)

Comment: It wasn't explicitly stated by the Dart team, but I expect the browser to become redundant for unit tests. There are configurable imports which are already implemented in the VM (not sure about dart2js) behind a flag, and when a `dart:html` library becomes available that doesn't depend on the browser, unit tests can load this one instead and run HTML tests without the browser. Because there is no official statement about this I don't know about a timeline.